# Read multiple value from as JSON format from a external service and store in composer registry

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I  am trying to read multiple value from as JSON format from a external service and store in composer registry. However it is getting error as below:

Error: Expected a Resource or Concept.

Please find attached my code below and help me understand.

```
concept TempReadings {
    o DateTime[] redDate
    o String[] minTemp
    o String[] maxTemp
    o String[] avgTemp
}
asset Temperature identified by uniqueId {
    o String uniqueId
    o TempReadings redTemp
}

transaction GetTempDetails {
    o String orderId
    o String prodId
    o String secureBoxId

}

event CreateTempDetailsEvent {
    o String uniqueId
}

async function GetTempDetails(uID){
    var factory = getFactory();
    var NS_M = 'org.acme.securebox';
    var uniqueID = uID.orderId + "-" + uID.prodId + "-" + uID.secureBoxId;
    var temperature = factory.newResource(NS_M, 'Temperature', uniqueID);
    const  temp = await request.get({ uri:  'https://<MYURL>/  $filter= ORDERID 
    eq "uniqueID" ', json: true });

    temperature.uniqueId = uniqueID;
    for(i=0;i<temp.d.results.length;i++){
        temperature.redTemp.redDate[i] = temp.d.results[i].date;
        temperature.redTemp.minTemp[i] = temp.d.results[i].tempMin;
        temperature.redTemp.maxTemp[i] = temp.d.results[i].tempMax;
        temperature.redTemp.avgTemp[i] = temp.d.results[i].tempAvg;

    }
    // save the order
    return getAssetRegistry(temperature.getFullyQualifiedType())
       .then(function (registry) {
           return registry.add(temperature);
       })
       .then(function(){
           var CreateTempDetailsEvent = factory.newEvent(NS_M, 
           'CreateTempDetailsEvent');
           CreateTempDetailsEvent.uniqueId = temperature.uniqueId;
           emit(CreateTempDetailsEvent);
       });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this - this works:

```
/** 
 * Track temperatures 
 * @param {org.acme.securebox.GetTempDetails} GetTempDetails - temperatures to be processed 
 * @transaction 
 */ 

async function GetTempDetails(uID){ 

var factory = getFactory(); 
var NS_M = 'org.acme.securebox'; 
var uniqueId = uID.orderId + "-" + uID.prodId + "-" + uID.secureBoxId; 

var temperature = factory.newResource(NS_M, 'Temperature', uniqueId); 
temperature.redTemp = []; 

const temp = await request.get({ uri: '<myURL>? $filter= ORDERID eq "uniqueId" ', json: true }); 

//this data below is a sample of what comes back from request response assigned to `temp` (I can't call your request URI :-)  - format your output if different

var temp = '{ "ID": "123", "ORDERID": "123", "date": "2018-01-01T00:00:00", "tempMin": "16", "tempMax": "24", "tempAvg": "20"}, { "ID": "456", "ORDERID": "456", "date": "2018-01-01T00:00:00", "tempMin": "16", "tempMax": "24","tempAvg": "20"} '; 

// stringify results 
var tempstr = JSON.stringify(temp); 

// create an array of objects 
var jsonobj = JSON.parse('[' + JSON.parse(tempstr) + ']'); 


for(i=0 ; i < jsonobj.length; i++ ) { 

    var redTemp = factory.newConcept(NS_M, 'TempReadings'); 

    console.log("ID field for this array element is " + jsonobj[i].ID); // all good 

    var str = jsonobj[i].date + 'Z';  // supplied date in `temp` isn't truly DateTime so...

    // convert the assumed string into an array. 
   //  eg    redTemp.redDate = [new Date('2011-04-11T10:20:30Z')]; 

    redTemp.redDate = [new Date(str)]; 
    redTemp.minTemp = [jsonobj[i].tempMin]; 

    redTemp.maxTemp = [jsonobj[i].tempMax]; 
    redTemp.avgTemp = [jsonobj[i].tempAvg]; 

    // temperature.redTemp = [redtemp]; 
    temperature.redTemp.push(redTemp); 

    console.log("temperature date for array redTemp element " + i + " is: " + temperature.redTemp[i].redDate); 

}  // end for 

// save the order to the ledger 

return getAssetRegistry(temperature.getFullyQualifiedType()) 
  .then(function (registry) { 
      return registry.addAll([temperature]); 
  }) 
  .then(function(){ 
      // var CreateTempDetailsEvent = factory.newEvent(NS_M, 'CreateTempDetailsEvent'); 
      // CreateTempDetailsEvent.uniqueId = temperature.uniqueId; 
      // emit(CreateTempDetailsEvent); 
       console.log("everything is done"); 
  }); 

} // end function
```